# My LSTM code give flat prediction and don't know what is wrong..Anyone can help take a look?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the code. I think the class `mylstm` has problem but I can not find it... The input is simple, which is just 7 columns data.

I tried to print out all the tensors but did not find what was wrong. Thanks for help!

```
class mylstm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, T, logger):
        super(mylstm, self).__init__()

        self.T = T
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.logger = logger


        self.lstm_layer = nn.LSTM(input_size = 7, hidden_size = hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
        #self.fc.weight.data.normal_()

    def forward(self, input_data):

        hidden = self.init_hidden(input_data)
        cell = self.init_hidden(input_data)
        for t in range(self.T - 1):
            if t < self.T - 1:
                self.lstm_layer.flatten_parameters()
                _, lstm_output = self.lstm_layer(input_data[:,t,:].unsqueeze(0), (hidden, cell))
                hidden = lstm_output[0] 
                cell = lstm_output[1] 
        y_pred = self.fc(hidden[0])
        return y_pred


    def init_hidden(self, x):
        return Variable(x.data.new(1, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).zero_())


# Train the model
class rnn:
    def __init__(self, file_data, logger, input_size = 7, hidden_size = 64, T = 10,
                 learning_rate = 0.01, batch_size = 128, parallel = True, debug = False):
        self.T = T
        dat = pd.read_csv(file_data, nrows = 100 if debug else None)
        self.logger = logger
        self.logger.info("Shape of data: %s.\nMissing in data: %s.", dat.shape, dat.isnull().sum().sum())

        self.X = dat.loc[:, [x for x in dat.columns.tolist()]].values
        self.y = np.array(dat.rtm_spp)
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.lstm1 = mylstm(input_size = input_size,
                               hidden_size = hidden_size,
                               T = T, logger = logger)

        if parallel:
            self.lstm1 = nn.DataParallel(self.lstm1)

        self.lstm1_optimizer = optim.Adam(params = filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.lstm1.parameters()),
                                           lr = learning_rate)

        self.train_size = 20000
        self.y = self.y - np.mean(self.y[:self.train_size]) # Question: why Adam requires data to be normalized?
        self.logger.info("Training size: %d.", self.train_size)

    def train(self, n_epochs = 10):
        iter_per_epoch = int(np.ceil(self.train_size * 1. / self.batch_size))
        logger.info("Iterations per epoch: %3.3f ~ %d.", self.train_size * 1. / self.batch_size, iter_per_epoch)
        self.iter_losses = np.zeros(n_epochs * iter_per_epoch)
        self.epoch_losses = np.zeros(n_epochs)

        self.loss_func = nn.MSELoss()

        n_iter = 0

        learning_rate = 1.

        for i in range(n_epochs):
            perm_idx = np.random.permutation(self.train_size - self.T-1)
            j = 0
            while j < self.train_size:
                batch_idx = perm_idx[j:(j + self.batch_size)]
                X = np.zeros((len(batch_idx), self.T - 1, self.X.shape[1]))
                #y_history = np.zeros((len(batch_idx), self.T - 1))
                y_target = self.y[batch_idx + self.T]

                for k in range(len(batch_idx)):
                    X[k, :, :] = self.X[batch_idx[k] : (batch_idx[k] + self.T - 1), :]

                loss = self.train_iteration(X, y_target)
                self.iter_losses[i * iter_per_epoch + j // self.batch_size] = loss
                #if (j / self.batch_size) % 50 == 0:

                j += self.batch_size
                n_iter += 1

                if n_iter % 10000 == 0 and n_iter > 0:
                    for param_group in self.lstm1_optimizer.param_groups:
                        param_group['lr'] = param_group['lr'] * 0.9


            self.epoch_losses[i] = np.mean(self.iter_losses[range(i * iter_per_epoch, (i + 1) * iter_per_epoch)])
            if i % 10 == 0:
                self.logger.info("Epoch %d, loss: %3.3f.", i, self.epoch_losses[i])
                y_train_pred = self.predict(on_train = True)
                y_test_pred = self.predict(on_train = False)



    def train_iteration(self, X,y_target):
        self.lstm1_optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = self.lstm1(Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor)))
        y_true = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_target).type(torch.FloatTensor))
        y_true = y_true.view(y_true.shape[0],1)
        y_pred=y_pred.squeeze(0)
        print(y_pred)
        loss = self.loss_func(y_pred, y_true)
        loss.backward()
        self.lstm1_optimizer.step()
        return loss.data[0]

    def predict(self, on_train = False):
        if on_train:
             y_pred = np.zeros(self.train_size - self.T +1)
        else:
             y_pred = np.zeros(self.X.shape[0] - self.train_size)

        i = 0
        while i < len(y_pred):
            batch_idx = np.array(range(len(y_pred)))[i : (i + self.batch_size)]
            X = np.zeros((len(batch_idx), self.T - 1, self.X.shape[1]))
            #y_history = np.zeros((len(batch_idx), self.T - 1))
            for j in range(len(batch_idx)):
                if on_train:
                    X[j, :, :] = self.X[range(batch_idx[j], batch_idx[j] + self.T - 1), :]

                else:
                    X[j, :, :] = self.X[range(batch_idx[j] + self.train_size - self.T, batch_idx[j] + self.train_size - 1), :]

            input_data = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).type(torch.FloatTensor))
           # print(self.lstm1(torch.randn(128,9,7)))
            #print(self.lstm1(X).data.numpy())
            y_pred[i:(i + self.batch_size)] = self.lstm1(input_data).data.numpy()[:,0]
            i += self.batch_size
        return y_pred


model = rnn(file_data = 'L.csv', logger = logger, parallel = False,
              learning_rate = .001)

model.train(n_epochs = 1000)

y_pred = model.predict()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be good if you can reduce your codes into the simplest form which still reproduce your problem. Asking people to debug over 200 lines of codes may be too big an ask. If you can give a small example of your problem, using a very simple NN model instead of the current one, many others will be willing to look into your codes and help identify the issue.